# Filtering in PowerBI - does user see it?

Tags: powerbi

I am building a map with PowerBI, and adding "County" to the visual filter.  I only want certain counties to be displayed on the visualization.

Right now, there is 1 county checkbox selected on the filter, so only one county is showing on the map.  If I share this visualization (i.e. "publish" it), will the user simply see the checkbox filters and be able to select other counties?  I need to have all other counties excluded for privacy concerns and I do not want users to be able to see checkbox options for other counties, let alone be able to display other counties on the map.

Answer (score 2):

You can set it so that it only appears in the filters pane but if privacy is important you need to either filter out the other counties at the query stage so they don't even exist behinds the scenes in the published report or else implement [Row Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-rls) to set who is allowed to see what counties by creating roles and rules you want.

Comment: Alexis, thanks.  If I'm hoping to create multiple visualizations for different counties, (ie each county would only be able to see their own data - so the county to be filtered will vary) - should I filter the data before it gets to PowerBI, or in the query view of PowerBI?  thanks.

Comment: If your consumers are accessing the report from the Power BI Service online, it doesn't really matter. Whichever you prefer. If they have access to the .pbix, then you'd need to filter before it gets into PowerBI to fully maintain privacy.

Answer (score 0):

You also can set the visiblity of the filter (buttom right) to `Not visible` or you can lock the filter (top right).

[image]

[image]